# Laravel Custom Query

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have this query

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(id) as id, title FROM `major` where university_id=1 group BY `title` order by id asc
```

I want to convert it into Laravel Query , I have a model majors and the function as follow

```
public static function retrieveByUniversityIDForWeb($universityId){
    return self::select(DB::raw('ANY_VALUE(id) as id, title'))->from('major')->where('university_id', $universityId)->orderBy('id','desc')->simplePaginate(6);
}
```

but its not returning me the results , query works in phpmyadmin. Any idea what I missed?

Comment: How are you accessing this method on model? Share the controller logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the method on your model which references its table by default. Also there's no need for using `ANY_VALUE` in your query. If you need it for some reason then you can change the select below to `selectRaw('ANY_VALUE(id) as id, title')`

```
public static function retrieveByUniversityIDForWeb($universityId)
{
    return self::select('id', 'title')
        ->where('university_id', $universityId)
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->simplePaginate(6);
}
```